# Using Google Places API to find nearby places BY TYPE (parks) for iOS SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, google-places-api, swift5

I'm pretty new to Swift/iOS app dev. so far, so I'm struggling to figure this out. Basically, I'm trying to make it so when the app opens (first screen is the map), it automatically finds nearby places **that are only parks** around the user's current location and have these locations annotated with markers on a map (**Google Maps**) using Google Places API for iOS using updated SwiftUI/Swift 5.0: **Using no storyboards!**. Table I types, in this case, *parks*: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

So far, this is the code I have... It uses GMSPlaceLikelihood of places nearby the user's location. This is more so an example of what I want to achieve, however using Google Places API nearby search instead so I can show only parks. Image of app running:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b6hh.png)

(The place's found from nearby are then listed in a table as shown on the image. This list is just for show)

Thanks in advance for any advice/help.

**GoogleMapsView.swift:**

```
@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
@ObservedObject var place = PlacesManager()

func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude, zoom: 14)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
    mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
    mapView.isIndoorEnabled = false
    mapView.isTrafficEnabled = false
    mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = false
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    
    place.currentPlacesList(completion: { placeLikelihoodList in
        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            print("total places: \(placeLikelihoodList.count)")
            
            for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList {
                let place = likelihood.place
                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
                let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                marker.title = place.name
                marker.map = mapView
            }
        }
    })
    
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
    //        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude, zoom: zoom)
    //        mapView.camera = camera
    mapView.animate(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.latitude, longitude: locationManager.longitude))
}
```

**PlacesManager.swift:**

```
class PlacesManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

private var placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

@Published var places = [GMSPlaceLikelihood]()

override init() {
    super.init()
    currentPlacesList { (places) in
        guard let places = places else {
            return
        }
        self.places = places
    }
}

func currentPlacesList(completion: @escaping (([GMSPlaceLikelihood]?) -> Void)) {
    // Specify the place data types to return.
    let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
        UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.types.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue))!
    placesClient.findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation(withPlaceFields: fields, callback: {
        (placeLikelihoodList: Array<GMSPlaceLikelihood>?, error: Error?) in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList {
                let place = likelihood.place
            }
            
            completion(placeLikelihoodList)
        }
    })
}
```

**ContentView.swift:**

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        GoogleMapsView()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .frame(height: 400)
        PlacesList()
    }
    .offset(y: 100)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

I suggest you visit this page, it describes the API in detail and shows examples how to call it with different parameters.

After you get the response (I suggest getting it in json format and using SwiftyJSON cocoa pod to parse it) populate the table.